# Creating a custom NodeJSDocker image on rhel7

Tags: node.js, docker, redhat, yum

I am building some base Docker images for my organization to be used by applications teams when they deploy their applications in OpenShift. One of the images I have to make is an NodeJS image (we want our images to be internal rather than sourced from DockerHub). I am building on RedHat's RHEL7 Universal Base Image (ubi). However I am having trouble configuring NodeJS to work in the container. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM myimage_rhel7_base:1.0

USER root

RUN INSTALL_PKGS="rh-nodejs10 rh-nodejs10-npm rh-nodejs10-nodejs-nodemon nss_wrapper" && \
    yum install -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs $INSTALL_PKGS && \
    rpm -V $INSTALL_PKGS && \
    yum clean all

USER myuser
```

However when I run the image there are no `node` or `npm` commands available unless I run `scl enable rh-nodejs10 bash`. This does not work in the Dockerfile as it creates a subshell that will not be usable to a user accessing the container.

I have tried installing from source, but I have run into a different issue of needing to upgrade the gcc/g++ versions despite them not being available in my configured repos from my org. I also figure that if I can get NodeJS to work from the package manager it will help get security patches and such should the package be updated.

My question is, what are the recommended steps to create an image that can be used to build applications running on NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided in the end to install node using the binaries rather than our rpm server. Here is the implementation

```
FROM myimage_rhel7_base:1.0

USER root

# Get node distribution from nexus and install it
RUN   wget -P /tmp http://myrepo.example.com/repository/node/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz && \
      tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xf /tmp/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz && \
      rm /tmp/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is a case where the best code is code you don't write at all. Take a look at https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container

It is a project that creates an image that has nodejs installed. This might be a perfect solution out of the box, or it could also serve as a great example of what you're trying to build.

Also, their readme attempts to describe how they get around the scl enable command.

> Normally, SCL requires manual operation to enable the collection you
>   want to use. This is burdensome and can be prone to error. The
>   OpenShift S2I approach is to set Bash environment variables that serve
>   to automatically enable the desired collection:
>
> - `BASH_ENV`: enables the collection for all non-interactive Bash sessions
> - `ENV`: enables the collection for all invocations of `/bin/sh`
> - `PROMPT_COMMAND`: enables the collection in interactive shell
>
> Two examples:
>   * If you specify `BASH_ENV`, then all your `#!/bin/bash` scripts do not need to call `scl enable`.
>   * If you specify `PROMPT_COMMAND`, then on execution of the `podman exec ... /bin/bash` command, the collection will be automatically
>   enabled.